# set http header asihttprequest

Tags: objective-c, ios, authentication, asihttprequest

I am using `ASIFormDataRequest` to post to web service. Now my server programmer says I should set HTTP headers and pass folowing parameters: `username='value'` and `password='value'`. This is because the web service uses authentication. How should i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[request addBasicAuthenticationHeaderWithUsername:@"yourUsername"
                                      andPassword:@"yourPassw"];
```

For more information about HTTP Authentication check out the  [ASIHTTP documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#handling_http_authentication) about it.

Comment: I had deleted my answer, if u feel that I copied ur answer & post then its totally wrong.

Comment: Your answer was identical to mine, word by word. Even if not copied it still wasn't adding any value.